# Currying enhanced components

Tags: reactjs, currying

I am having difficulty understanding currying applied to react components.

LanguageContext.js

```
 <LanguageContext.Consumer>
   {value => <Component languageContext={value} {...props} />}
 </LanguageContext.Consumer>
)
```

Navbar.js

`export default  withLanguageContext(withStyles(styles)(Navbar))`

a simpler example.

`const add = x => y => x + y`

If we call add(2) it will return a function with curried  value of x. In order to get result of this  function,  we need to call add(2)(2) which will return 4. So, in the Navbar  when we do this
`withLanguageContext(withStyles(styles)(Navbar))`

According to my understanding,  return a function that expects props in order to return after that LanguageContext.Consumer.  However, we are not passing any props explicitly. My expectation was something like this in this case:  `withLanguageContext(withStyles(styles)(Navbar))(props)`

Answer (score 2):

Props are more or less implicitly passed to **React Components**, but under the hood they technically *are* functions, so perhaps this would be easier to illustrate with a react functional component.  Suppose this was your `NavBar`:

`const NavBar = props => (<div>...</div>);`

We clearly see that yes, it is a function, but we **never** call it like one, i.e. `NavBar(props)`, the react framework instantiates it like a component, i.e. `<NavBar {...props} />`, or in the case of JSX literals (already has the props baked in), like `{NavBar}`.

This pattern in the React world is known as a Higher Order Component (HOC), as opposed to the functional programming name of Higher Order Functions. They are functions that return other react components.

[Higher Order Components](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html)